# qtip content filtered with a condition

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

This is my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $('#calendarx').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        events: [
            <apex:variable var="prioritem" value="false"/>
            <apex:repeat value="{!displayRows}" var="row">
                <apex:outputtext value="," rendered="{!prioritem='true'}"/>
                <apex:variable var="prioritem" value="true"/>
                {
                    title:'{!JSENCODE(row.title)}',
                    start: new Date({!row.startDateYear},{!row.startDateMonth},{!row.startDateDay}),
                    end:   new Date({!row.endDateYear},{!row.endDateMonth},{!row.endDateDay}),
                    allDay: true,
                    url: '{!JSENCODE(row.url)}',
                    className: 'calcolor-{!JSENCODE(row.color)}',
                    typ: '{!JSENCODE(row.typ)}',

                    end_date: '{!JSENCODE( (row.enddate2) )}',
                    start_date: '{!JSENCODE( (row.startdate2) )}'
                }
            </apex:repeat>
            /*{!calendarJson}*/
        ],
        eventClick: function(event) {
            if (event.url) {
                window.open(event.url);
                return false;
            }
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element, view){
            element.qtip({ 
                position: {
                    corner: { 
                        target: 'topMiddle', 
                        tooltip: 'bottomMiddle' 
                    }
                },
                style: { 
                    width: 300,
                    color: 'black',
                    name: 'light',
                    background:'white',
                    name: 'blue'
                },
                content:

                    "<b>Campaign:</b> " + event.title + "<br/>" +                     
                    "<b>Start date:</b> "+event.start_date+"<br/>"+
                    "<b>End date:</b> "+event.end_date+"<br/>"       


            });
        }
    });
});
```

i have 2 different objets on a calendar and i want to show different qtip for different objects.
I want to change the qtip´s content:

```
"<b>Campaign:</b> " + event.title + "<br/>" +                     
 "<b>Start date:</b> "+event.start_date+"<br/>"+
 "<b>End date:</b> "+event.end_date+"<br/>"
```

using like filter  typ: '{!JSENCODE(row.typ)}',
it contains `campaign` or ´event´.
I´m using it to distinguish the two objects.

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
 eventRender: function(event, element, view){
               console.log(event.typ);

               if (event.typ=="campaign"){
                   var table = $('<div><b>Start date:&nbsp </b>'+  event.start_date   +
                    '<br/><b>End date:&nbsp </b>'+  event.end_date    +
                    '<br/><br/><b>campaign:</b>' +
                    '<br/></div>');
              }
              else {
                      var table = $('<div><b>ciao:&nbsp </b>'+  event.start_date   +
                    '<br/><b>End date:&nbsp </b>'+  event.end_date    +
                    '<br/><br/><b>Events:</b>' +
                    '<br/></div>');


                   }

                element.qtip({ 
                    position: {
                        corner: { 
                            target: 'topMiddle', 
                            tooltip: 'bottomMiddle' 
                        }
                    },
                    style: { 
                        width: 300,
                        color: 'black',
                        name: 'light',
                        background:'white',
                        name: 'blue'
                    },
                    content: table.html()
```